# $Hostname.contains | Where {$_.name -Match ("test")})

Tags: powershell

Hello I have done this script in PowerShell

```
$hostname = get-content env:computername
$host = "Desk"
if ($hostname.contains | Where {$_.name -Match ("test")})
{
$chars = [char[]]"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
$name = [string](($chars[0..25]|Get-Random)+(($chars|Get-Random -Count 
10) -join ""))

Rename-Computer -NewName $host$nam
Write-Host -foregroundcolor Yellow "New Computername is $host$name"
}

else {
Write-Host -foregroundcolor Red  "This is not a test pc "
Start-Sleep -s 10
Exit
}
```

which is working fine when I am looking only for the word "test"
what i am trying to do is to have more search criteria   like

```
if ($hostname.contains | Where {$_.name -Match ("test" -or "test01" -or 
"test02" -or "test03" -or "test04" -or "test05")})
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-Match` operator is a case-insensitive Regex match. This means that pattern `"test"` would match `test01`, `Zerotest`, `test1323454`, `Anythingtestanything`, etc. If you know more about the patterns you want to test, you can tailor your regex match if you want to continue using regex.

For example if you know that all host names will begin with `test` and end with digits, you can use `-Match "^test\d+$"`. You should use `-CMatch` if case-sensitivity matters.

- `^` is the start of a string.
- `\d+` is one or more digits
- `$` is the end of string

See [About Comparison Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-6) to see more information on `-Match`, and it contains a link about regular expressions.

Comment: To be more exact the only thing that I want to match is the last 3 characters
Thank you

Comment: You want to match the last three characters or match something and select only the last three characters?

Comment: yes,
 I tried this code and it seems to work. 
 if (((((((($hostname.contains("SER")) -or ($hostname.contains("L01")) -or ($hostname.contains("L02")) -or ($hostname.contains("L03")) -or ($hostname.contains("L04")) -or ($hostname.contains("L05")) -or ($hostname.contains("L06"))-or ($hostname.contains("L07")))))))))

Comment: You can use `-Match` for that as well, e.g. `$variable -Match "L02$"`. If all hostnames end with L0<somedigit>, you can use `$hostname -Match "L0\d$"`.

Comment: I have to admit that I'm slightly confused by what is in your `$hostname` variable. You use `$hostname.contains` like `contains` is a property. But in your comments you use it like a method call. You are also referencing a `name` property as well. I think if you can explain what `$hostname` contains, we can easily find a solution for you. If it is truly a hostname of the current system, then you don't need `| where {$_.name ....}`.

Comment: the hostname is just to call the name of the system and to check it if contains ser
i am new with PowerShell but it worked

but it seems is working

this script is just a part of a bigger script

Answer (score 0):

How about this way...

```
$Hostname = 'Lab01'
$Hostname = 'LabTest01'
$Hostname = 'NewLabTest'
$Hostname = 'Test05'

if ($Hostname -Match 'test|test01|test02|test03|test04|test05')
{ "$Hostname matches criteria" }
Else {Write-Warning -Message "$Hostname does not match criteria"}


# Results

WARNING: Lab01 does not match criteria
LabTest01 matches criteria
NewLabTest matches criteria
Test05 matches criteria
```